# CFPreferencesCopyAppValue misbehaving on mavericks?

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist, osx-mavericks

I am using [`CFPreferencesCopyAppValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html) to read a key from my plist but the problem is that even if the plist does not exist, its still returns some value.
When I explicitly write on the terminal `defaults read myplist`, and then call the api, it correctly determines that plist does not exist and returns NULL.

I am building my code on OS X 10.7.5. When I run my application on OS X 10.8, it always works correctly but when I run it on OS X 10.9 (developer preview 3), it starts doing the above behavior.

I have also tried deleting the plist and emptying the trash but it still reads some value - it seems like it has the info. in memory and does not care about the current value on disk.

Can someone please help? And is someone else also seeing this weird behavior?

Comment: Mavericks is a "moving target": it will be undoubtedly different by the final release. Since this is the case, how could anyone say anything with any certainty about it? Besides, it's also under an NDA so the best thing to do would be to ask this question in an Apple Dev Forum.

Comment: This is caused by deleting the plist. Never manipulate preferences via the Finder, always use NSUserDefaults, CFPreferences, or defaults.

Comment: yes agreed! I was actually trying to cover for the case if user trashes it. But, in the end we thought that user trashing it is his mistake and we cannot cover for it.